# Are there other ways to verify a URL is valid and exists?

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

I'm trying to find if there are ways other than using HttpURLConnection to check that a link is working, but I'm not find any other options. It seems most other methods I come across are just checking that the format of the URL is valid, but doesn't connect to it to check for a response code.

Comment: If you don't connect to that URL then how do you know that URL is not valid? Maybe you mean the hostname?

Comment: If your goal is to avoid transferring the body, you could try HEAD instead of GET. Not sure if it is supported everywhere (or allowed). (See RFC 2616 9.4 quote: _"This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification."_)

Comment: The only to verify that a URL is active is to connect to it and send a message.  The @Luis Manrique answer is mostly correct.  The only problem is that not all URLs accept GET.  Some require POST, PUT, or other methods.  You must know the Method and the URL to access (and thus verify) it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a specific URL with java, you can try to make a ping to this URL and check if it's working or not. Try this example!

https://java2blog.com/how-to-ping-url-and-get-status-in-java/

[image]

Comment: Maybe he didn't know how to do it with HttpURLConnection and is trying to get another options for this, I don't know...

Comment: In that case it would still be a link-only answer ... you may want to cite the relevant parts of the solution you linked. Links can die.

Comment: Additionally, there are other status codes that indicate the host is up, etc. that aren't just 200/OK.  301/302 redirects, etc.

Comment: ping only checks the connection to the host not the full URL.

Comment: @Fildor That's true, I have lack of experience answering in Stackoverflow I only tried to get the link.